# Did Ramunaja allow lower-Caste Sri Vaishnavas inside temples

Tags: temple, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita, ramunajacharya

I now many temples had rules as to who can and cannot enter and a hygiene code as well which may not have been followed by some lower varnas. Apart from the inner chamber where the murti resides (for Brahmins alone may go in there) did Ramunaja ever compose a treatise of temple rules that allowed lower Varnas who were to fit to be at a Sri Vaishnava temple to be at that temple? If not what about other Vishsitadvaiatana and Sri Vaishnava scholars?

Comment: There is no śāstriya niṣedha on temple entry of even a Cāṇḍāla, let alone a Śūdra. However, garbhagṛha is not a place for everyone, usually arcakas are supposed to be there.

Comment: And I was giving a genuine comment. Your second question is not relevant to the OP's question @estimator And it seems that you have two accounts on this site.
If there is a single śāstra, which does state that temple entry is allowed on the basis of jāti, please mention it. On the other hand, I can quote śāstras, which do show that even Cāṇḍālas can enter temples.

Comment: @Bingming only one. its just name change.

Comment: That depends on tradition to tradition. Usually Shankaracharya tradition doesn't allow women and sudras to read vedas or enter temples. Other traditions do have own formulations and allow the same. Tho, I'm not sure about particularly Sri Vaishnava, but Ramanandi (usually a sect that emerged from that philosophy) does has openness for all the caste, I've heard that they also allow Sudras to study and upgrade their verna, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @User29449 Ādi Śaṅkara mentions the śāstrīya niṣedha regarding Vedādhyayana by non-dvijas (including Śūdras, women, etc.), he doesn't talk about temple entry or state any restriction regarding that on the basis of jāti. Rāmānuja is also against Vedādhyayana by non-dvijas. This is stated clearly in his Brahmasūtra bhāṣya. Rāmānuja, Nimbārka, Madhva, Ādi Śaṅkara, Rāmānanda, Baladeva Vidyābhūṣaṇa, all agree that only dvijas have the adhikāra to do Vedādhyayana. And the restriction of Vedādhyayana has nothing to do with temple entry.

Comment: @Bingming From what I've heard, Karpatri, of Shankaracharya's order, was against temple entry by Dalits and Sudras. He prohibited them entry into Somnath and Vishwanath temples. So your idea that there isn't any discrimination on the basis of jati in the Shankara order is False. I don't see any parallel sampradayas to Shankaracharyas that have done the same (even a single example). Ref: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E7s27kjUUAMmyFJ?format=jpg&name=medium, https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E7s27kjVoAMhtWI?format=jpg&name=medium

Comment: @User29449 tbf he never said it didn't exist just that major works on this topic by Shankara don't attribute to this idea of temple restrictions.

Comment: @Haridasa Neither I'm saying about on Shankara, rather it is Shankara tradition.

Comment: @User29449 please correct me if I am wrong I don't wanna create frivolous arguements, but it seemed you were blaming or disapproving of Bingmings comment when he was only talking about the person and not the tradition.

Comment: @Haridasa His reply was attributing my reply as false when I was talking about Tradition. Even Shankara as person has written a lot of misfit stuff on his commentary, but that's a different topic altogether.